# После восстановления перенесённого вопроса остаётся плашка

Tags: дефект, перенос-вопросов, инструменты-модератора

Порядок действий:

- Перенести [вопрос](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6244/178988) с меты на сайт
- Восстановить вопрос
- Разблокировать вопрос

Плашка о переносе осталась на месте, хотя по идее должна была исчезнуть, поскольку вопрос снова открыт на мете:

[image: скриншот]

При это в описании очистки истории переносов говорится, что разблокировки должно быть достаточно в случае отклонения переноса:

[image: скриншот очистки истории переноса]

> #### очистить историю переносов
>
> Иногда сообщения переносят на другие сайты ошибочно, и их нужно перенести обратно. Очистка истории переносов удалит также все прежние записи о переносах, разблокирует и переоткроет вопрос, а также восстановит все ответы, которые были удалены в результате переноса. **Внимание!** Это деструктивное действие, которое удаляет все следы переноса из общедоступной истории версий. Если вы просто хотите убрать сообщение «перенос отклонён», достаточно разблокировать вопрос.

Comment: Получилось два одинаковых живых вопроса на разных сайтах, так что ли?

Comment: Отметка переноса - это просто атрибут перенесенного вопроса. Там где-то в мод меню есть кнопка для её снятия.

Comment: @PashaPash, тут говорится, что должно быть достаточно разблокировать: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfSa4.png

Comment: @Qwertiy так это разные сообщения: перенос отклонен и плашка о переносе. Разве нет?

Comment: @alexolut, возможно. Но должен же быть способ очистить не затирая историю.

Comment: Модераторы должны страдать!

Comment: @alexolut, так плашку-то все видят

Comment: Я же не сказал, что другие не должны страдать :)